# WPF Datagrid restrict input with combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, datagrid

i am using the EF and the MVVM approach to get a bunch of data records in an `ObservableCollection`. This `ObservableCollection` lives in a ViewModel.
The `ViewModel` is than bound to a `DataGrid`. This works just fine.

For the sake of data consistency i now want to turn a bunch of columns in the `DataGrid` into `ComboBoxes`. So the user can only choose from a predefined set of values. These predefined values are also stored in the database (You can think of it as a lookup table). I can load the values from the database and also put it in an `ObservableCollection`. But now i wonder how can i bind this to the `DataGrid`, since i can only specify one `ItemSource` for the `DataGrid`.
Is this even the right approach in WPF?

Answer (score 0):

Bind the `ItemsSource` property of `DataGridComboBoxColumn` to your values from the lookup table.

Then bind `SelectedValueBinding` to the field in the main collection.

If you are using normalised values (i.e. numeric values mapped to the items in the lookup table), then you should also set the  `SelectedValuePath` and `DisplayMemberPath` properties.